# How to wait between instructions in a .vbs script?(Just for fun)

Tags: windows, vbscript, cd-rom

i am creating a just for fun batch file to do the same as in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3nQK_53NAI).

I don't know much about programming and i also can barely read what it says in the screen in that video from youtube.

I found this code online:

```
do

Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7" )
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection

if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next ' cdrom
End If
```

I saved it as a .vsb script, and it looks like it work, but it all happen so fast that the tray closes at the half. 
How could i modify it to wait a couple of seconds once it is open?

Answer (score 3):

Add sleep command to make it sleep for five seconds (the argument is milliseconds) in the for loop

```
WScript.Sleep 5000
```